# Implement Apple Push Notification in Java

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications

I am looking to implement push notifications for iphone using java. My search tells me I have two alternatives javapns and java-apns.

Can someone advise me, which of the library should I use for my project. It seems that the javapns is not much in active development and there are a few unfixed bugs on the google groups project page.

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: haven't used, but as per the community activity, the later (java-apns) is more recent and active than the other.

Comment: this is exactly what i came up with too, but is the java-apns mature enough remains the question

Comment: that can only be said after using it, may be this link can give you some help. https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns/wiki/Compare-with-Javapns